# Detecting all object in Image API .NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, feature-detection

I am working on a project C# and I have to write a code that detects all the objects inside an image (if not all as much as possible).

is there any good API to do that in .NET? 
I tried Cognitive Services but they do not give me the detected objects. only what inside the photo.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the AForge.NET Framework:
They have some neat examples too.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Comment: Thanks, I read about it and it seems nice. but I wanted to be sure about it.